# Maven Build Time for Angular Project

Tags: angular, maven

I have an Angular project that is surrounded by a simple Spring Boot shell so I can deploy it as a war.

```xml
                <!-- build the angular project -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources-1</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/dist/myapp</directory>
                                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

I would like to generate (or use the resources plugin filtering to modify) a very simple file that will contain the build time for the war. My preference would be a TS file that could be imported into the project:

```js
export const MAVEN_BUILD_TIME : string = `${mavenBuildTime}`;
```

Can anyone help?